# Postfix/Dovecot setup only accepting messages to one user

Tags: postfix-mta, dovecot

I have installed Postfix and Dovecot on my Raspberry Pi. The Pi is behind the domain `scubbo.org`. When I send email (from a GMail account, via web) to pi@scubbo.org, the mail is delivered:

```
pi@raspberrypi /etc/postfix $ whoami
pi
pi@raspberrypi /etc/postfix $ mail
Heirloom mailx version 12.5 6/20/10.  Type ? for help.
"/var/mail/pi": 1 message 1 new
>N  1 Jack Jackson       Sat May 24 00:06   42/1825  This was sent from gmail to pi@scubbo.org
```

But when I try the same thing to scubbo@scubbo.org, it's not delivered:

```
pi@raspberrypi /etc/postfix $ su - scubbo
Password:
scubbo@raspberrypi:~$ mail
No mail for scubbo
```

Any ideas why? There's no special config that I can see for either:

```
pi@raspberrypi /etc/postfix $ grep -ir 'pi' .
[...only results for "pipe", "recipients", etc...]
pi@raspberrypi /etc/postfix $ grep -ir 'scubbo' .
[...only results for the domain, not the user...]
```

---

**EDIT:**

- postconf -n: http://pastebin.com/VaREy2q4
- /etc/aliases: http://pastebin.com/RiRmKmTj
- Logs during receipt of a message to pi@scubbo.org: http://pastebin.com/Ya89utFY
- Logs during receipt of a messages to scubbo@scubbo.org: http://pastebin.com/nudG61xx

Comment: can you post the output of `postconf -n` and the log lines generated by postfix to help you better.

Comment: Found the solution (see my answer below) - if you provide an answer, I'll happily accept/upvote it for your help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @clement suggesting closer reading of logs, I found my answer - I had had an alias set up in user `scubbo` /etc/aliases, which I'd removed, but I didn't realise I also had to run newaliases. All working now!